# Call Rollback Transaction in Other function - Node+KnexJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I have a transaction that executes an insert in my database, but I need to execute another simpler insert, and I would like to call the transaction rollback if there is an error in the second insert.

```
await knex.transaction(async trx => {                
    const queries = []
    for(const dadoResultado of dadoResultados.dados){
        const query = app.db.raw(`
            insert into dadoResultados
                ...
            `)
            .transacting(trx)
            .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err.message))

            queries.push(query)
    }
    await Promise.all(queries)
        .then(trx.commit)
        .catch(trx.rollback)
})

await app.db.raw(`
    INSERT INTO resumoacompanhamentos (num, value)
        values (13, 50)
`)
```

Code Modify:

```
try{
    await app.db(async trx => {
        for(const data of values.dados){
            await trx.raw(`
                insert into values(code_inst, money, subscription, version, first_name)
                select
                    b.code_inst,    
                    b.money
                    p.subscription,    
                    a.version,                  
                    b.first_name
                from (VALUES (${data.code_inst}, ${data.money}, ${data.first_name}) b(code_inst, money, first_name)
                inner join table_P as p
                on p.code_inst = b.code_inst
                AND p.version = b.version
                AND p.code_inst = b.code_inst
                left join table_A AS a
                on a.subscription = p.subscription
            `)        
        }

        const sum_value_final = await app.db.raw(`
            SELECT 
                SUM(money) AS money
            FROM values
                WHERE first_name = ${first_nameFile}
                AND subscription = ${values.dados[0].subscription}
        `)

        const sumValues = await sum_value_final.rows[0]

        await app.db.raw(`
            INSERT INTO resume_table (code_inst, subscription)
                values (${sumValues.dados[0].code_inst}, ${sumValues.dados[0].subscription)
        `)                            
    })
} catch(err){
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
}
```

ERROR TWO:

> select * from (select *) - subquery in FROM must have an alias

Comment: Up, can help-me?

Answer (score 0):

You are using transactions wrong. When you are returning `Promise` from transaction handler function you should never call explicitly trx.commit() / trx.rollback(). Also you are calling global knex for getting connection for transaction and then using `app.db.raw` for running queries which is really strange...

Anyways are you trying to do this:

```
try {
  await app.db.transaction(async trx => {                
    for(const dadoResultado of dadoResultados.dados){
      await trx.raw(`
          insert into dadoResultados
          ...
      `);

    }

    await trx.raw(`
      INSERT INTO resumoacompanhamentos (num, value)
        values (13, 50)
    `)

  });
} catch (err) {
  res.status(500).send(err.message);
}
```

Comment: The selection of the second query, makes a selection based on the previous insert of the same transaction, is it possible to do it this way considering that you can only do the second if the first is finished?

Comment: This way the second is ran only if the first queries are finished. If any of the queries in for loop fails it throws an exception and the last query will not be ran.

Comment: error: select * from (select *) - subquery in FROM must have an alias

Comment: You need to debug your queries by yourself, I just showed how knex transactions work. I would never recommend using knex raw the way you have written the queries anyways ‍♂️Good luck!